# Google Maps v3 InfoWindow adding text to input

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I've got a marker with an InfoWindow which contains a text input. I'd like to populate this with a value dynamically, but it isn't happening...

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skeniver/9TbaU/) to show what I mean:

```
info1.setContent('<input type="text" id="infotext"></input>');
info1.open(map, marker);
$('#infotext').val('yes');
```

I suspect that it's got something to do with the order of the code; the infowindow probably isn't actually shown when I set the value.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is Repetition of **IDS** as IDs must be **unique**, Use class name instead like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     info1.setContent('<input type="text" class="infotext" />'); <!-- mind closures -->
     info1.open(map, marker);
     $('.infotext').val('yes');
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9TbaU/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I see yours works, but where do I have duplicate IDs?

Comment: @skeniver When you click on map it generates the marker and based on markers you're generating text inputs so each inputs have the same IDs, so each and every-time inputs will be having same ID and it won't work with duplicate IDs.

Comment: Even if I only add one marker, it doesn't work though: http://jsfiddle.net/skeniver/9TbaU/4/

Comment: @skeniver NO, the last fiddle you shown doesn't contain a single marker, it allows to create multiple markers!

Comment: Yes, you can create multiple markers, but if you only create one, then there is only one so it can't confuse IDs